# Contact form 7 hide and show fields depending up on the condition

Tags: javascript, plugin-contact-form-7

I have using contact form for my website and the code i have using is below

```
<label> Your Name (required)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
[email* your-email] </label>

<label> Your Country
[select country id:CountryDropDown first_as_label "Select" "United Kingdom" "United States"] </label>

<label id="UkStates"> State
[select state "London" "Scotland"] </label>

<label id="UsaStates"> State
[select state "San Francisco" "New York"] </label>

[submit "Send"]

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("UkStates").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
  function displayTextField() {
    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").value;
    if (dropDownText == "United Kingdom") {
      document.getElementById("UkStates").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("UkStates").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

This code is working only one condition.
My question is how to create more condition by using JavaScript.

for example: country field have United States also, so if selecting United States want to display only US states.

please excuse if question is extended to large.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question. If you want to do an `if` statement with two conditions, just use `&&` (AND) or `||` (OR):

```
if (dropDownText == "United Kingdom" && condition2 == "some") {
  // do something
}

if (dropDownText == "United Kingdom" || condition2 == "some") {
  // do something
}
```